# search widget is not working in release apk

Tags: android, search, widget, android-appcompat, searchview

I'm having a strange issue(for me at least).
my app works fine with debug apk. but when I create release apk then it shows error in searchwidget.
I'm using support library 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

this is my code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
    mi.inflate(R.menu.searchmenu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchwidget);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat
            .getActionView(searchItem);
    if(null!=searchManager ) {   
     searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    }
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered
            Programs.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered
            Programs.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return true;
        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

my menu code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item 
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:id="@+id/searchwidget"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"></item> 


</menu>
```

first I thought it is proguard problem therefore i used this

```
-keepclassmembers class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView{
}
```

but still same problem.

can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: hmmm `-keepclassmembers`? are you sure? not `-keepnames`?

Comment: I dont know what to use. should i use -keepnames ?

Comment: just think ... what is needed to create class via reflection ... its members or name?

Comment: anyway i have just tested few things `-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }` works for me

Comment: I have the same kind problem with ListFragment. Not able to perform item click in release apk.  Please help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to add

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
```

to proguard-rules.pro file.

Somehow it is related to proguard obfuscation, probably a bug in SearchView. (some version affected, some not)

Answer (score -4):

disable  the progaurd or make it as "false" from build.gradle

It will increase the size but will get the work done.

it worked for me